# JavaFX put Gridpane into a BorderPane

Tags: javafx, gridpane, borderpane

First of all I am a beginner in Java. I'm trying to create a Monopoly game in Java with JavaFX. I drew the board in a Gridpane.

My question to you guys is how can I put that GridPane in the center of a BorderPane. Atm the gridpane takes the whole screen. I want it in the center of the borderpane and use the other space for a menu and other pane's.

**The GridPane**

```
public class BordView extends GridPane {
private GridPane spelbord = new GridPane();

public BordView() {
    initNodes();
    layoutNodes();
}

private void initNodes(){
}

private void layoutNodes(){
    RowConstraints rowsEdge = new RowConstraints();
    rowsEdge.setPercentHeight(14);
    RowConstraints rowsMid = new RowConstraints();
    rowsMid.setPercentHeight(8);

    ColumnConstraints colEdge = new ColumnConstraints();
    colEdge.setPercentWidth(14);

    ColumnConstraints colMid = new ColumnConstraints();
    colMid.setPercentWidth(8);

    this.getColumnConstraints().addAll(colEdge, colMid,
            colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colEdge);
    this.getRowConstraints().addAll(rowsEdge, rowsMid,
            rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsEdge);

    this.setGridLinesVisible(true);
}
```

**The BorderPane**

```
public class GameView extends BorderPane {
BorderPane borderpane = new BorderPane();
public GameView() {
    layoutNodes();

}
private void layoutNodes() {
    borderpane.setCenter(BordView);
}
```

Comment: It would be much better to copy-and-paste the code in the question than to have a link to a picture of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the current information posted I can only make a educated guess:

You are using `BorderPane` with composition **and** inheritance. Most likely `borderpane` is never added to the scene graph. You should add the content to the `GameView` itself:

```
this.setCenter(BordView);
```

instead of

```
borderpane.setCenter(BordView);
```

But I'm not even sure where you get the `BordView` from...

Also maybe you don't need inheritance there at all.

BTW: If there are no other elements in a `BorderPane` except the center, it will fill the whole `BorderPane`.

From the javadoc

> If resizable, [the center node] will be resized fill the center of the border pane between the top, bottom, left, and right nodes.